# How to use an external API in Google Apps Script that requires an API Key?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest, urlfetch

Is it possible to use external API's within google apps script that require API key's?

How would you get data from an API that requires a key using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Question is too broad. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apps Script has [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) which fetches resources and communicate with other hosts over the Internet. This includes URL requests with API keys.

Example from this [Using Google Sheets and Google Apps Script to Work with APIs](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2016/02/24/using-google-sheet-and-google-apps-script-to-work-with-apis/):

sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //get active spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data'); //get sheet by name from active spreadsheet


  var apiKey = 'Your API Key'; //apiKey for forecast.io weather api
  var long = "-78.395602"; 
  var lat =  "37.3013648";    
  var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey +"/" + lat +"," + long; //api endpoint as a string 

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get api endpoint
  var json = response.getContentText(); // get the response content as text
  var data = JSON.parse(json); //parse text into json

  Logger.log(data); //log data to logger to check

  var stats=[]; //create empty array to hold data points

  var date = new Date(); //create new date for timestamp

  //The following lines push the parsed json into empty stats array
    stats.push(date);//timestamp 
    stats.push(data.currently.temperature); //temp
    stats.push(data.currently.dewPoint); //dewPoint
    stats.push(data.currently.visibility); //visibility

  //append the stats array to the active sheet 
  sheet.appendRow(stats)

}
```

Comment: NEVER store an API key as plain-text in your source code.